# convergence and divergence of sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If we have a sequence $\{a_n\}$ in $R$,
$b_n = (a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n)/n$

(a) an example of a sequence $a_n$ in which $a_n$ diverges while $b_n$ converges

(b) an example of a bounded sequence $a_n$ such that $b_n$ diverges

Could you give me some help?

I  thought about a sequence $\{1,2,3,4,\ldots, n\}$ but this obviously doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try any other sequence? Here is one: $(-1)^n$. It answers one of the three questions.

Comment: Oh! (-1)$^n$ will work for (a)! Although it diverges, b$_n$ will converges to 0! Thank you!

Comment: For (b), try a sequence that looks like this: $0$, then three $1$'s, then nine $0$'s, then twenty-seven $1$'s, and so on forever.

Comment: @Andre Nicolas. Is there something simpler??Your example could never have occurred to me.Also I gave a wrong answer. Didnt read the question properly, my bad.

Comment: Well, the idea is simple. Put together alternating strings of $0$'s and $1$'s, with the lengths of the strings growing fast. This is to make sure that when we reach the end of a string of say $0$'s, the $0$'s dominate, and same with strings of $1$'s. This makes the average of partial sums bounce around a lot. Speed $3^n$ or $4^n$ works nicely. Any other type of example we try to construct has us needing fine control over the average of partial sums, so sounds hard to handle.

Comment: Thanks, that is a great explanation!

Comment: Also, you neeed to correct the c) statements. Note for instance that $\limsup \sup a_n$ does not make sense.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Hi, Andre, For (b), I used your example. I tried to prove b$_n$ is bounded by contradiction. Suppose it converges. Then, by the definition of convergent sequence, d(P$_n$, P) < $1/n$ for n>= N. We can add large enough number B to N so that $b_(N+B)$ is 1. Then, when $n$ = $N+B$, d(P$_n$, P) >= $1/n$. Contradiction! Is this correct?

Comment: There is not enough detail, by a lot. Maybe you should use $4^n$ or $10^n$ instead of $3^n$ to give yourself some slack. Show there are infinitely many $n$ such that the average up to $n$ is $\gt 2/3$, and infinitely many $n$ such that the average up to $n$ is $\lt 1/3$. That will show non-convergence.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Could you point out what's the error in my proof so that I can fix and add details please?

Comment: That $(b_n)$ is bounded is so clear that one need not even mention it: each number being added is $0$ or $1$, and we divide by $n$, so the average is between $0$ and $1$. We need to show the sequence $(b_n)$ does not have a limit. In a comment above, I described briefly how to do it. If you work on it a while, and have trouble, I can write an answer. Can't be a comment really, too little space.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Could you write an answer for me please? I've worked on it but I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We give a detailed  answer to (b). Too detailed, perhaps, since it may make a simple idea look more complicated than it is.

Consider the sequence $a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots$ that goes as follows:
$$1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,\dots,1,0,0,0, \dots,$$
where we have $1$ one, then $9$ zeros, then $90$ ones, then $900$ zeros, then $9000$ ones, and so on. The sequence $(a_n)$ is bounded, since every entry is zero or one.

Note the following features of this sequence. The term $a_{10}$ is at the end of a string of $9$ consecutive zeros, the term $a_{100}$ is at the end of a string of $90$ consecutive ones, the term $a_{1000}$ is at the end of a string of $900$ consecutive zeros, and so on.

(i) We will estimate $b_{10}$, $b_{1000}$, $b_{100000}$, and so on.

(ii) We will separately estimate $b_{100}$, $b_{10000}$, $b_{1000000}$, and so on.

**Estimates for (i):** The number $b_{10}$ is $\frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots +a_{10}}{10}$, so it is the average of the first $10$ terms of the sequence $(a_n)$. Of these $10$ terms, $9$ are $0$'s, so $b_{10}\le \frac{1}{10}$ (of course we have equality).

Now look at $b_{1000}$. This is the average of the first $1000$ terms of the sequence $(a_n)$. Of these terms, at least $900$ are zeros. (Actually, $909$ are zeros.) So no more than a $100$ are ones, and therefore $b_{1000}\le \frac{1}{10}$.

Now look at $b_{100000}$. This is the average of the first $100000$ terms. Of these, the last $90000$ are zeros, so at most $10000$ are ones, and therefore $b_{100000}\le \frac{1}{10}$.

The same reasoning shows that if $n=10^k$, where $k$ is odd, then $b_n\le \frac{1}{10}$.

**Estimates for (ii):** Look at $b_{100}$. The last $90$ of the terms we are averaging are $1$ (actually, exactly $91$ of the terms are $1$). So $b_n\ge \frac{9}{10}$.

Look at $b_{10000}$. The last $90000$ terms we are averaging are $1$, so $b_{10000}\ge \frac{9}{10}$.

Similarly, if $n=10^k$ where $k$ is even, then $b_n\ge \frac{9}{10}$.

**Concluding the non-existence of the limit:** We show that $\lim_{n\to \infty} b_n$ does not exist. One can do a formal $\epsilon$-$N$ argument or do it informally. For the informal version, there are arbitrarily large $n$ of Type (i), where $b_n\le \frac{1}{10}$. There are also arbitrarily large $n$ of Type (ii), where $b_n\ge \frac{9}{10}$.

So the limit of the $b_n$, it it existed, would have to be simultaneously $\le \frac{1}{10}$ and $\ge \frac{9}{10}$. That's impossible.

If you need the $\epsilon$-$N$ version of non-existence, I can supply it. But as a hint we can take $\epsilon$ say $1/4$.

Comment: Nicolas could you show me ϵ-N version of non-existence please? I think I need to know the formal way to prove this.

Comment: And I think "Similarly, if n=2$^k$ where k is even" should be Similarly, if 10=2$^k$ where k is even". just a minor error ^^. And you mean we can take ϵ say 1/10?

Comment: @InfimumMaximum: Thank you for spotting the $2^k$ where $10^k$ was intended. As to $\epsilon$, certainly the $1/10$ you suggest would be fine, but $1/4$ will do as well, because of the very big gap between $1/10$ and $9/10$: the supposed limit $b$ cannot be simultaneously within $1/4$ of the infinitely many values of $b_n$ that are $\le 1/10$ and the infinitely many that are $\ge 9/10$.